# "in" vs "inout" in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

"inout" is described in the Swift documentation as a way to be able to modify variables within functions and have that modification reflected in the global scope. But I see functions defined with `in` only and I'm unable to find a reference for the `in` keyword by itself.

[Example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shape/path(in:)) with the `path(in:)` method on `Shape`.

What's the difference between `in` and `inout`?

Comment: You can read about [Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166) in the Swift Programming Language book

Comment: I totally did not relate that section to the "in" word. It looked so much like a special keyword that I got confused. Thank you for the reference @JoakimDanielson!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function from your example has the following prototype:

```
func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path
```

`in` - external parameter name.
`rect` - local parameter name

- Local parameter names are used in the body of the function/method
- External parameter names are used when calling the function/method.

As a result, you can write a function with the following prototype:

```
func someFoo(in rect: inout CGRect) {
   rect = .zero
}
```

And call it in the following way:

```
var someRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5, height: 3)
someFoo(in: &someRect)
```

Comment: The correct terms are "argument label" and "parameter name".

Answer (score 3):

`in` is an argument label helps to make the call more readable it can be anything descriptive

```
func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path --- path(in:.....)
func path(from rect: CGRect) -> Path  --- path(from:.....)
func path(to rect: CGRect) -> Path  --- path(to:.....)
```

`inout` is a keyword used in function parameter composition when you need to mutate the sent parameter origin value and not to be wrote when you call it

```
func changeSend(rect: inout ModelRef)  --- changeSend(rect:.....)
```

Comment: That makes complete sense, I was curious whether there was some functionality behind `in` or not, but turns out it doesn't! Thank you :]

Comment: Sorry to confuse the issue, but "in" does have a special meaning in closures.

Comment: @DuncanC in closures but not what op means here

Answer (score 1):

In the example you shared, `in` is not a keyword, it's an argument label.

```
func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path
```

An argument label can be anything like -

```
func path(inside rect: CGRect) -> Path
```

However `inout` is a keyword, that does what you described.

```
func incrementAndPrint(x: Int) {
    x += 1
    // Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable:
    // 'x' is a let constant
}


var value: Int = 0
// Note the '&' in front of value
incrementAndPrint(x: &value) 
print("value : \(value)")

func incrementAndPrint(x: inout Int) {
    x += 1
    print("x : \(x)")
}
```

However this is not to say that `in` is not a keyword in Swift, it is. See this example -

```
var names: [String] = ["Alex", "Bob"]
for name in names {
}
```